# Analogue of zoom in css? Transform: scale() property as zoom property

Tags: javascript, css, zooming, transform, scale

There is a zoom property in css, it does what it needs, but there is no support in browsers (Firefox in particular). There is also a transform: scale () property, but the fact is that the main_div block becomes visible when using transform: scale (), which is not when using the zoom property. I need exactly this behavior.

Can the transform: scale() property be applied in such a way that it works like a zoom? Or what analogs does the zoom property have? How to be in this situation?

Here is my code. You need to check in Google Chrome, since Firefox's zoom property does not work
https://jsfiddle.net/tj2349f5/1/

html

```
<div id='main_div'>
  <div id="second_div">Hello</div>
</div>
<input class="test_button" type="button" name="button_name" value="test">
```

JavaScript

```
let test_button = document.querySelector('input.test_button');
test_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //second_div.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)';
  second_div.style.zoom = 0.5;
});
```

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you actually want and why scale doesn't provide it? In particular I don't understand  "but it shrinks the content div itself". If you include some code which shows why scale it not what you need it might be clearer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks that makes it clearer. However, on my device at 3000px the red never shows (I guess my device is narrower than yours). What I do see is that on the zoom option the amount of scroll bar changes (i.e. the second div has actually changed dimensions) while on the scale option the scroll bars do not change (i.e. the second div has kept the same space). So you want FF to change the dimensions on a scale too.

Comment: I have put what may be a workaround into an answer but as I can't see exactly the same as you do when running your code I am not absolutely certain it does what you need. Please could you try it and let me know.

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you. Yes, you got it right. When I use transform: scale() and zoom out on the second_div block (green), the main_div block becomes visible (it's red) when I scroll forward, which is not when using the zoom property. Apparently the zoom property of the second_div block (green) "correctly" edits (adjusts). Here I need so that the main_div block is not visible when the second_div block is scaled down.

Comment: @AHaworth I will now try your solution and write you an answer

Comment: @AHaworth My device is narrower than yours (1360 px). Perhaps, to see this problem, you need to resize the second_div block. For example, increase from 3000 to 10000 or more. Or vice versa, reduce

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a 'real' CSS zoom and a scale is that a scaled element does not change the space it takes up whereas a zoomed one does.

I am not absolutely sure whether this code does what you want as on my device I don't see the red appearing as described in the question [I think this is because my device is narrower]. What it does is change the width and height of the zoomed element alongside the scaling.

The effect on Chrome that I see is that the scrollbars change the same amount whether using this code or the real CSS zoom whereas using scale only the scrollbars don't change at all.

```js
let test_button = document.querySelector('.test_button');
test_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  second_div.style.height = second_div.offsetHeight * 0.5 + 'px';
  second_div.style.width = second_div.offsetWidth * 0.5 + 'px';
  second_div.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)';
  test_button.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

div#main_div {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  background: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

div#second_div {
  height: 3000px;
  width: 3000px;
  background: green;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id='main_div'>
  <div id="second_div">Hello</div>
</div>
<button class="test_button">CLICK TO MAKE IT LOOK LIKE A REAL CSS ZOOM BUT USING SCALE AND DIMENSION SETTING</button>
```

Note: if you scale back up remember to restore the dimensions as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't help. Moreover, it changes the very size of the second_div block (pixels), which in my case should not be allowed.
As I understand it, when you change the scale of an element or window, the number of pixels is preserved, but they just decrease or increase in size. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it changes the size because I can't see any other way of getting the scale to behave more like a zoom (a zoom actually altering the size in terms of what is seen). Sorry not to help.

Comment: Thanks for trying. If you still find a solution, please write it down here. I'll be waiting